# Trouble stopping a tomcat server that is running a web application with a while (true) loop

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I'm developing a web application to be deployed onto Tomcat.  When Tomcat is started, I use a servlet (in web.xml) to call a Java class:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Consumer</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>start</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.sample.Consumer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

My Consumer.java subscribes to a queue on an AMQP server. I achieve this by using a `while (true)` loop, which works fine in a standalone Java program. Itt also works in the context of the web application, but I can never stop my Tomcat server (within my NetBeans IDE), and I believe that the while loop is the culprit.  Here is some code:

```
public class Consumer {
    public Consumer()
        consume();
    }

    private void consume()

        ...

        while (true) {
            // Await incoming messages from queue
            // Process message
        }

    }

}
```

Is there a better way to handle this?  Or to signal a stop to break out of the loop?

Thanks!

---

Updated to use ServletContextListener:

```
public final class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    public ApplicationListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("***** Stopping Consumer *****");
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        System.out.println("***** Starting Consumer *****");

        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledConsumer(), 0, 15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    public class ScheduledConsumer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Consumer k = new Consumer();
            k.consumeOnce();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm struggling with whether to deploy message queue consumers as web applications (like you did) or system level java clients. If you a minute, please have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230781/architecture-of-a-web-application-using-message-queues. I would greatly appreciate any insight you have gained on the matter since you asked your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some suggestions, but they require that you modify your architecture a bit in order to more nicely play with your container environment.

Servlet containers support "listeners" that can get notification of various events. Specifically, one of them is the `ServletContextListener` which gets notified when the context (aka. webapp) is being brought into service (via the `contextInitialized` method) and when it is being brought out of service (via the `contextDestroyed` method).

My recommendation would be to do the following:

1. Change your `Consumer` class's constructor so that it does not automatically call `consume()`; instead, add a public method like `consumeOnce` and don't use a loop at that level at all
2. Write a `ServletContextListener` that has a `Consumer` and a `Thread` reference as members as well as a `volatile boolean stop` flag; in `contextInitialized` it should create a new `Consumer` object, then launch a new (daemon) thread that:

   - Calls `Consumer.consumeOnce`
   - Calls `Thread.sleep` for an appropriate amount of time
   - Loops over the previous 2 steps until the stop flag is true
3. Have your `ServletContextListener`'s `contextDestroyed` method set the stop flag to `true` and call `Thread.interrupt` on the running thread.

I'm sure I'm missing some exact details, but that's the general idea. When Tomcat shuts down, your code will be notified of the shutdown and you can cleanly terminate your own looping-thread. You may need to provide a way for the `Consumer` to abort an attempt to consume whatever it consumes (e.g. stop waiting to pull an object from an empty queue) if it doesn't abort when it gets a `Thread.interrupt` signal. (For instance if you use an `Object.wait()` in order to wait for a monitor notification, then you'll want to change that so it uses a wait with a timeout so that you won't block forever).

Comment: I'm open to modifying my architecture, in fact I've already taken a step closer towards your solution. Instead of using a servlet to call the consumer, I added a class implementing ServletContextListener, and it will call the class on contextInitialized. I used contextDestroyed to set a stop flag to false, and I modified the while(true) to be while(stop flag is equal to true). That didn't work, however. I still ran into the same issue. I like your idea, I will try to implement the thread and let you know how it goes. I might have a question or two more but, for now, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Christopher, please see my updated ServletContextListener above. It seems to work! A very elegant solution - thank you. Did I implement it as you had envisioned? The server does completely stop now.

Comment: I might have re-used the same Consumer instance, but that may or may not be advantageous depending on exactly what it does. Use of an Executor gets you extra points.

Comment: Be careful with an Executor, though: since you are using a ScheduledExecutor, you might run into "jobs" that last longer than the schedule cycle. As you have it, I think you'll be okay: you have a single-threaded executor so you won't have jobs running simultaneously. But, it does mean that you won't execute jobs as quickly as possible: your pipeline will drain at a constant rate and may get "clogged" with an ever-increasing flow of messages that aren't being processed fast enough.

Comment: Is there a performance gain by re-using the same Consumer instance? I will keep in mind your advice about the Executor. You're right, it will be limited to a single-threaded executor. I'm going to deploy this application as one .war, however I may have an additional (but as separate .war's) three applications, each with the same architecture, but consuming from different queues. I don't imagine that would be a problem...

Comment: You will achieve a tiny performance gain by not creating another object and then having the GC collect it. Only you can determine whether there are other factors such as initialization, setting up the connection to the MQ, etc. If you ask me, every little bit helps.

Answer (score -2):

You have to place the code with the loop in a different thread and start the thread from your consumer.

```
private void consume() {
  Thread x = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while(true) {
      ....
      }
   });
   x.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason why introducing a new thread would cause a severe error on server start? The error is SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.sample.Consumer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

Comment: This won't help at all: the Thread will be a non-daemon thread and won't allow the JVM to shut down. Even making this into a daemon thread would never shut-down cleanly. If the webapp were to be redeployed and the JVM not restarted, then this would cause a PermGen (and some regular heap) memory leak due to ClassLoader pinning.

Comment: Is interesting that you say this. I do this in my jobs for the same producer/consumer case using an MQ architecture, and I have had no problems at all starting or stopping the play server. I'm running it with netty, but it also deploys as a war to be run in tomcat/jboss/..., I'd be surprise if that gives problems.

Comment: Stopping the server *might* be an issue depending upon how the server shuts itself down. Tomcat does not call System.exit() when shutting down unless something goes wrong and an exception is thrown. Your suggestion will definitely cause a PermGen leak if merely *redeploying* the webapp (without a JVM restart).

Comment: Thanks for the info. It stills surprises me though, and if that how it works, it feels more like a bug than a feature to me. I believe you, but I'm going to try this myself to see it with my own eyes, it shouldn't work like that.