# RabbitMQ Work Queue Configuration Questions

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I have two questions about RabbitMQ Work Queues:

1. As I understand it from the RabbitMQ tutorials, it seems that if I have a basic queue consumer client (just a basic "Hello, World!" consumer) and then I add a second consumer client for the same queue, then RabbitMQ will automatically dispatch the messages between those two queues in a round robin manner. Is that true (without adding in any extra configuration)?
2. My consumer clients are configured to only ever receive one message at a time, using `(GetResponse response = channel.basicGet("my_queue", false)`.  Since I am only ever receiving one message at a time, is it still necessary to set a prefetchCount (`channel.basicQos(1)`) for fair dispatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes
2. No

However, your two questions 1 and 2 are not compatible.  If you are using a consumer, it is designed to have messages pushed to it, and you don't use `Basic.Get`.  When you use a consumer, you will need to use `Basic.QoS` to specify that the consumer can only "own" one unacknowledged message at a time.  RabbitMQ will not push additional messages beyond the QoS limit.

Your alternative is to "pull" from the queue using `Basic.Get`, and you will control your own destiny as far as how many messages you run at a time.

Does this make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, I seem to be "pulling" then. Will the work queue model still work with "pulling" clients (the round robin dispatching)? My original intention was to have messages pushed to my clients, however the clients are deployed as Tomcat web applications, and I found that a while(true){} loop did not play nicely with Tomcat (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164517/trouble-stopping-a-tomcat-server-that-is-running-a-web-application-with-a-while). As a result, I use Java's ScheduledExecutorService to run a client every X milliseconds, which will request only one message from the queue

Comment: I believe that whoever pulls the next message from the queue gets the next message. Round robin is irrelevant because you are not dispatching anything.

Comment: Hm, so with my current model it is possible that one of my "consumers"  will pull more messages than another? I ask because it is starting to sound like it may be more advantageous to implement these consumers as Java clients on a system level as opposed to Tomcat web applications.

Comment: Without being more familiar with your application, it's difficult to say. However, if you are using a pull model, it shouldn't matter if one processes more than the other; either they are both operating at full capacity or one/both is idle. I'm an industrial engineer, and have studied queuing theory, so maybe I'm overthinking your problem...

Comment: Have you considered using Apache Camel as a thin layer in your Java app between the consumers and AMQP? Also, it sounds strange to have message consumers running in Tomcat. Essentially Tomcat is a tool that allows you to run HTTP request consumers. If your messages do not arrive in an HTTP request, Tomcat is probably unneccessary complexity.

Comment: While I've heard of Apache Camel, I haven't ever looked into it. I'm reading a few articles about it now. I initially wanted the consumers to be native Java processes, but my requirements were to use tomcat. It does add much unnecessary complexity, but I guess that it does add additional portability/manageability. I'll see what I can find out about Apache Camel.